# xml spreadsheet not change Format number using mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel, export-to-excel

i use following xml file and open it in Excel

```
the view 
@{
    Layout = null;
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "1.xls");
}

    <?xml version="1.0"?> <ss:Workbook xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
        <ss:Styles>
            <ss:Style ss:ID="DateLiteral">
             <NumberFormat ss:Format="General Number"/>
            </ss:Style>
        </ss:Styles>
        <ss:Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
            <ss:Table>
                <ss:Row>
                    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="DateLiteral">
                        <ss:Data ss:Type="Number">123.01</ss:Data>
                    </ss:Cell>
                </ss:Row>
            </ss:Table>
        </ss:Worksheet> </ss:Workbook>
```

the format is still on General even i give format number.
any help?

Answer (score 2):

look here for the custom codes to use:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/number-format-codes-HP005198679.aspx

But I would look at replacing this:

```
        <ss:Style ss:ID="DateLiteral">
         <NumberFormat ss:Format="General Number"/>
        </ss:Style>
```

with the below if wanting a number

```
        <ss:Style ss:ID="DateLiteral">
         <NumberFormat ss:Format="0"/>
        </ss:Style>
```

or below if wanting 12000 to display as 12,000.00 in custom rather than general

```
        <ss:Style ss:ID="DateLiteral">
         <NumberFormat ss:Format="#,##0.00"/>
        </ss:Style>
```

I have spent all day hunting on the internet to find the above so I will answer this on any XML Spreadsheet query I find as it was annoying to find and difficult too.